# Finding MLE of $\theta$

Tags: probability

I came across the following problem online and I've been able to show part a by using the CDF of the exponential:

$$P(X < \theta) = \frac{1}{2}$$

CDF of X: $1 - e^{-\lambda \theta} = \frac{1}{2}$

$$e^{-\lambda \theta} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\ln(e^{-\lambda \theta}) = \ln(\frac{1}{2})$$

$$-\lambda \theta = -\ln(2)$$

$$\theta = \frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda}$$

Which I believe is the result that they meant in part a (I think they mean $\lambda^{-1}$ instead of $\lambda^1$).

But not I'm struggling to find the maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$. I tried doing something like $L(\theta) = \underset{i} \Pi \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and I end up getting $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ which would be the correct MLE for $\lambda$ (http://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/exponential-distribution-maximum-likelihood) but I'm still confused about how to find it for $\theta$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A standard result on MLEs is that they are equivariant, so that the MLE of $\theta = \frac{\ln2}{\lambda}$ is just $\ln2$ over them MLE of $\lambda$.

**Postsript:** If you want to do this by brute force instead of exploiting the equivariance of MLEs, you can do this:  First, observe that $\lambda = (\ln 2)/\theta$, so that the likelihood function for $\theta$ is
$$
L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{\ln 2}\theta e^{-x_i(\ln2)/\theta}\right) = \frac{(\ln2)^n}{\theta^n} e^{-(\ln2)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/\theta}
$$
and
$$
\ell(\theta) = \ln L(\theta) = \text{constant} - n\ln \theta - \frac {\ln 2} \theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,
$$
and then
$$
\ell\,'(\theta) = \frac{-n}\theta + \frac{n{\large \bar x} \ln 2}{\theta^2} = \frac{-n( {\large\bar x} \ln 2 - \theta )}{\theta^2}.
$$
thus $\ell\,'$ changes signs when $\theta = \bar x \ln 2 = \dfrac{\ln 2}{\widehat\lambda}$.

Comment: I'm asking about part b, where we find the mle $\hat{\theta}$ of $\theta$. Is this what your answers is addressing?

Comment: Part (b)  is what I answered, except the part about unbiasedness.  You wrote: "But not I'm struggling to find the maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$.", so that's the part I answered. $\qquad$

Comment: @Auser : I've updated my answer somewhat.